# Converting points from MySql database to WKT lines using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, well-known-text

In MySql database I have points (pairs of latitudes and longitudes represented as doubles) like this:

```
LATITUDE | LONGITUDE
---------|----------
45.045664| 46.084528
26.938933| 60.903848
       .....
```

Now, what I need is to get these points from my database (which is not a problem at all) and echo them in a WKT format or WKT line (this part I don't know). This PHP script is going to be a part of an API used by Windows App.

How can I convert points to WKT format?

Perhaps there is a plugin I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use string concatenation to create the [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) you need.  So if you want points just do:

```
"POINT("+lat+" "+lon+")"
```

or for LineStrings:

```
line = "LINESTRING(";
for(int i=0;i<coords.length;i++){
    line+=coords[i].x+" "+coords[i].y+",";
}
line=line.substring(0:len-1); //remove last comma
line+=")";
```

Comment: Oh, I also thought about this way but it seemed so simple to me. Thank you.